# Когда был отозван сертификат?

Tags: сертификат, цифровая-подпись

Есть программа, подписанная отозванным (на данный момент) сертификатом.

Дата установки на 1 день позже указанной даты подписи файла, вроде бы на тот момент сертификат отозван не был.

Можно ли как-то проверить когда и по какой причине был отозван этот сертификат, а так же, безопасно ли использовать эту программу?

[image: скриншот подписи]

[image: скриншот сертификата]

Answer (score 2):

CRL и OCSP возвращают дату отзыва, и если повезет, причину.

Но даже если эта дата позже даты подписи - как-то опираться на нее нельзя. Во первых, сертификат мог уйти на сторону задолго до отзыва. Во вторых - при отзыве владелец сертификата мог ткнуть любую причину.

Я отзывал сертификаты дважды, через разных провайдеров (один раз потеряли certrequest, второй - запросили не на то доменное имя). Оба раза провайдеры про причину не спрашивали. С таким же успехом я мог бы отозвать украденные сертификаты, через ту же самую форму.

Причем в случае кражи я бы именно так и сделал - зачем объявлять всему миру, кто у конторы данные увели (если можно не объявлять, и за это ничего не будет).

Так что надеятся, что в случае реальной кражи сертификата будет указана именно причина keyCompromise - нельзя.

Comment: Возвращают куда? Вот есть сертификат, что с ним делать, чтобы её увидеть?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно через openssl проверить (https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9968/38/how-to-check-the-certificate-revocation-status). или через повершельный модуль https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/ocsp-client-tool.aspx. может быть есть еще онлайн чекеры.